# Dynamic div elements and associating events with these div

Tags: javascript

I am creating dynamically multiple `div` elements using JavaScript. Below is the code I have used:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  var d1 = document.createElement('div');
  d1.id = "div" + i;
  var l1 = document.createElement('label');
  l1.innerHtml = "Hello";
  d1.appendChild(l1);
  var line1 = document.createElement('hr');
  d1.appendChild(line1);
  document.body.appendChild(d1);    
}
```

Output:

Hello

---

Hello

---

Hello

---

Now I want to dynamically append event say `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` so that whenever I move cursor over a particular `div` element say `div1`, `div2` or `div3`, that respective `div` section should change color (say blue) and when cursor moves out it should return to its original color.

I have tried working out but I am unable to retrieve the `div` id's which I have created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to select by ID. You already have the element, so go ahead and add handlers to it.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
  var d1 = document.createElement('div');
  d1.id = "div" + i;

  var l1 = document.createElement('label');
  l1.innerHtml = "Hello";
  d1.appendChild(l1);

  var line1 = document.createElement('hr');
  d1.appendChild(line1);
  document.body.appendChild(d1);

  d1.onmouseover = function() {
     this.style.color = "#00F";
  };
  d1.onmouseout = function() {
     this.style.color = "";
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build your handlers and then assign them in the loop:

```
var mouseover = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#AAF';
    },
    mouseout = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '';
    };
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var d1 = document.createElement('div'),
        l1 = document.createElement('label'),
        line1 = document.createElement('hr');
    d1.id = "div" + i;
    l1.innerHtml = "Hello";
    d1.appendChild(l1);
    d1.appendChild(line1);
    d1.onmouseover = mouseover;
    d1.onmouseout = mouseout;
    document.body.appendChild(d1);
}​
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/vfVCm/

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are created dynamically it may be better to use event delegation and attach the event listener to the parent element instead of every element that you're dynamically creating. This way your listener will work even for elements created after it's attached. DOM events bubble, and an actual target of an event is available as `event.target`. Here is an example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <p id="event1">A</p>
  <p id="event2">B</p>
  <p id="event3">C</p>
</div>

// call on DOMContentLoaded
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "p") {
    alert("Clicked element " + e.target.id);
  }
});
```

​
See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVTGV/).